# How to execute testng test cases with shared webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, hp-alm

I want to report each step of my selenium test case in HP ALM. Reporting has to be done in parallel with execution i.e. after 1st step is executed it has to be reported in ALM and so on. I am writing status of each test case as pass/fail in excel file which in turn reported in ALM.

I have made seperate classes for each step and tried executing each step in command prompt using testng.xml file
The command used is:

```
java -cp “.\bin;.\libs\*” org.testng.TestNG -testnames “Login” testng.xml
```

This executes the first step successfully and return the output as pass/fail in my excel file.

Now when I execute 2nd step (as second class) it will again run `@BeforeSuite` Method which creates a separate instance of browser which I don't want as I want to proceed from that particular point where my 1st step completed.

Note: I created a separate class for Browser Initialisation and declared my webdriver static (initialised in `@BeforeSuite`) and inherit my test cases from this class so that webdriver is shared among all.

My requirement in brief is to run test cases one by one (not as a complete suite) with webdriver instance shared among all the test cases.

I apologize for not putting my code as it is client specific.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Singleton class for the webdriver and it should work

Comment: first of all, the execution of @BeforeSuite means that you execute a second suite. With one java call, all your tests should be executed. what do you mean with "when execute 2nd step"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a [Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) product from Agiletestware which contains java annotation package which can be used together with TestNG and Selenium WebDriver to report test case result to HP ALM. It even can upload a screenshot of failed test case to ALM.

Please see the docs: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/selenium-webdriver/

Disclaimer: I'm a Bumblebee developer.